# can props be used in a useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a question that is if you can use props inside `useEffects`

[image]

Comment: Yes you can, props are just values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Props can be used in useEffect hook. Props are just values, when it is used in a useEffect dependency array, the component will re-render.

```
// This will only re-run if the value of `props.count` changes
useEffect(() => {
  fetchSomeData(props.count);
}, [props.count]);
```